# What is the worst case scenario for Dinitz's algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, network-flow

The complexity of [Dinitz's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinic%27s_algorithm) (used to find maximum flow in a network) is *O(V²E)*. I am trying to find a network, which is forcing the algorithm to use as much steps as possible.

I was thinking about a complete graph with some smart configuration of capacities, but I am not able find anything, that would seem to be clearly the *worst case*.

*It is a homework for my Algorithms class, please post advices to point me in the right direction, not complete solutions. Thanks a lot!*

(Sorry about my English.)